# How to don't shrink the top nav when overlay menu is open

Tags: javascript, css, properties, navbar, overlay

I got a problem with myNav overlay menu.
When is active and i scroll the page is going on shrink the top mainNav.

Does someone have the solution already?

How can I remove the shrinking when the overlay menu is open?

Thanks

//SHRINK

```
    var navbarCollapse = function() {
    if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
        $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
    } else {
        $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
    }
};
```

---

//OPEN `enter code here`
var iconMenu = document.querySelector('.icon-menu'),
menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

```
iconMenu.addEventListener('click', openMenu);


function openMenu() {

    if (menu.classList.contains('open')) {
        menu.classList.add('close');
        iconMenu.classList.remove('icon-closed');

        setTimeout(function() {
            menu.classList.remove('open');
        }, 200);

    } else {
        menu.classList.remove('close');
        menu.classList.add('open');
        iconMenu.classList.add('icon-closed');
        iconMenu.classList.remove('.nav-link');
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code!

Comment: check above please

Comment: do u need some css?

Comment: Need the html and css as well. Give us enough code to reproduce an example. If you're using any libraries (Bootstrap, jQuery etc) then mention that as well.

Comment: do u have any instant messaging where to talk
you can reply the answer here  to give you credit